# Java + GWT + GSON on server side

Tags: gwt, gson

I already read that there is no possibility to run [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in GWT client code, but that it is possible to run it in **server code**.

The latter one is which I'm trying to achive, but not getting to work. I thought any class within the com.whatever.server package has access to the whole JRE namespace including reflection. It seems that that is not the case. So how managed all those developers to use GSON in GWT server code? (I'm new to GWT, so the answer may be really easy.)

Thanks.

**EDIT**: My setting is as follows:

- test.gwt.xml contains: `<source path='client'>` and `<source path='shared'>`
- the client uses `private final TestServiceAsync testService = GWT.create(TestService.class);` and invokes `testService.testMethod();`
- TestService interface and TestServiceAsync are located in package client
- the TestServiceImpl implemented in test.server uses `Gson g = new Gson();` and so forth

The exception thrown is *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson*. But it seems that it is raised no matter whether the method contains GSON code or not (it is sufficient that it contains the GSON import-statement).

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason you can't use GSON on the server-side of your GWT app. What errors are you encountering with this? Are you sure your `server` package is not being GWT-compiled on accident?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your results?

Comment: This sounds less related to GWT and more related to your build path not including references to the necessary GSON code.

Comment: My build path contains gson.jar, which is located in /war/WEB-INF/lib/gson/* and the gson library is marked for export.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Okay solved it: The jetty configuration does not find the gson library within /lib/gson/, it should just be located in /lib. Thank you for your hints.

Answer (score 3):

This is a class path problem. GSON is not in the classpath. Which IDE do you use? if u use eclipse - 
1. right click the project
2. build path
3. configure build path
4. select "libraries" tab
5. click "add jars..."
6. in the popup choose the correct location for each of the necessary jars.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a JSP/Servlet webapplication, you just need to drop 3rd party JAR files in /WEB-INF/lib folder. If the project is a Dynamic Web Project, then Eclipse will automatically take care about setting the buildpath right as well. You do not need to fiddle with Eclipse buildpath. Don't forget to undo it all